# Java literal to divide by a very big number

Tags: java

I have a code in which I need to divide an integer by a very big number e.g. 12345678912. I used long but it still gives error as `The literal 12345678912 of type int is out of range`. 
Code for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //rest of the code 

    long x = 12345678912; //<--error is in this statement

    System.out.println(y/x); //<---y is an integer which is having some value in rest of the code.
}
```

I know that the maximum value that an unsigned long can hold is 2^(64)-1. But then, I want to know, how to achieve this in Java? Is there any way to achieve it directly, or I need to implement any algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

You need to tell that the data type is long by appending literal `l` or `L`

```
  long x = 12345678912L;
```